# Looking for thoughts, help in migrating database from Postgres (under Heroku) to SQL Azure

Tags: sql, heroku, azure-sql-database, postgresql-9.1, database-migration

Would the approach to migrate from Postgres to MySQL also work for a database migration from Postgres (under Heroku) to SQL Azure? If not, can someone help in understanding what strategies to adopt? I'm considering the following:

1. Build a fresh database schema under SQL Azure and change database.yml to the SQL Server adapter (not sure how)
2. Migrate the complete schema (tables and entity relationships — don't need data). And, change database.yml to the SQL Server adapter (not sure how) .
3. If neither works — figure out a way to sync data between Postgres and SQL Azure.

Thoughts, ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a rails application, were using ActiveRecord and were using database migrations, this is fairly simple. Follow this (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2011/09/14/using-active-record-with-sql-azure.aspx) guide to get your app working against SQL Azure, upload your code changes to Heroku, run `heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate` and you are done.

If you were not using database migrations, your task will be harder. I suggest using PGBackups to export data from Heroku Postgres (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) and finding a way to load this SQL to SQL Azure.